# .htaccess <If> statement invalid command when running Mamp Pro and apache 2.4+

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp-pro

I'm running Mamp Pro 4.4.1 with Apache 2.4.28. 
Anytime I use an 'if' statement in my .htaccess file such as

```
<If "req('Host') != 'www.wooga.com'">
    RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.wooga.com$1
</If>
```

results in 'Invalid command 'If', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration'.

However, setting up a local server without Mamp and the If parses fine. Is this a setting within a Mamp config somewhere?

thanks!
Johnny

Comment: Doesn't Mamp 4.4.1 come with Apache 2.2.34?